# Invalid constant value for List of Stateless Widgets

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

```
    class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List pages = const [
    MessagesPage(),
    NotificationsPage(),
    CallsPage(),
    ContactsPage(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: pages[0],
      bottomNavigationBar: _BottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

There’s an Invalid constant value error in `body: pages[0]` if I call the Widget directly like `body: MessagesPage()` then there’s no error.
I tried making everything const but nothing’s helping.

Is there any update in the new version of Flutter or have I done some mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `const` keyword:

```
  class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List pages = const [
    MessagesPage(),
    NotificationsPage(),
    CallsPage(),
    ContactsPage(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(//remove const keyword here
      body: pages[0],
      bottomNavigationBar: _BottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nicely written.

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Just a doubt, Do I need to write const keyword in the return of those widgets or that is optional?

Comment: no need to use keyword `const`

Comment: @Prerak no need to write `const` keyword in body

Comment: Thanks @RavindraS.Patil :)

Comment: Most welcome @Prerak happy to help you ,enjoy your ride with flutter

Answer (score 2):

remove `const`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( // here need to change
      body: pages[0],
      bottomNavigationBar: _BottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
```